# Differences between 'every' and 'each'

Tags: quantifiers

Would anybody possibly elaborate the differences between these?

Or, when/where- in which situations- would you rather use the followings?

> Each student
>
> Every student

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just want to point out few differences between "each and every".

**It's only "each" that is used as a pronoun, not "every"**.

**Examples** -

> 1. They don't cost $10 together, rather each costs $10 (here we can't use "every)
> 2. They don't cost $10 together, rather every/each one of them consts $10.

**With abstract nouns, only "every" is used, not "each"**

**Examples** -

> 1. He has every reason to worry about his friend. (we can't use "each" here)

**"Every" is used to say how often something happens.**

**Examples** -

> 1. You will find a bus to London from here every two hours.

**We use "Every" to mean "all in a group", and "each" to mean "one by one, individually"**

**Examples** - Study the example sentences carefully

> 1. After all the children assembled in the playground, the principal handed each child a beautiful present. (He handed them out one by
>      one.)
> 2. After all the children assembled in the playground, the principle handed every child a beautiful present. (He gave them all)

I can't think of any other differences. So I ask other people also to add here.

Thanking you.

Comment: They both are determiners but “every” functions only as adjective whereas “each” can function as adjective, pronoun and adverb. Only “every” can be used with adverbs.

Comment: Would anyone please explain me what "rather" means here? and if is it a contracted form of"rather than or not?

Comment: It was used to add some extra information, that is opposite to the one just mentioned. You can also replace "rather" with "instead" here. Got it?

Answer (score 3):

- Use **each** to mean "one by one". (Individual)

  > Each student was called to the principal's office.

  You can also use "every" here to mean "all students were called" but it will sound like all students were sent to the principal's office *at the same time.*
- Use **every** to mean "all". (General)

  > Every student passed the test.

  "Each student passed the test." is not wrong but the sentence sounds weird.

Comment: 'Each' can also be used as 'all' in some sentences like: [Each | every] T-shirt costs 10$ in this shop.

Comment: Yes; but there is a _very small_ difference. "**Each** t-shirt costs $10." sounds closer to "It costs $10 **per** t-shirt." while "**Every** t-shirt costs $10." sounds closer to "**All** t-shirts cost $10."