# Is it redundant to say "each and every volunteer"?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

In the following acknowledgements I am confused that why it should be "each" and every" rather than just "every".

> We sincerely appreciate the commitment and hard work of each and every
>   volunteer.

Source: certificate of appreciation by Oriental Connect International Volunteer Association Limited.

I learned from [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/19777/10484) that "each" means "one by one", and "every" "all in a group". But does "each and every volunteer" which indicates literally "all volunteers in a group and one by one volunteer" make sense? And is the saying equal to just "every"? I mean, what is the point that I have missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Each and every" is a frozen phrase that is used to express an entirety of some group or set. It uses the repetition of ideas for emphasis.

> Each and every one of you will receive a gift.

This is somewhat stronger than saying

> Each of you will receive a gift.

or

> Every one of you will receive a gift.